# Vimeo.com upload failure

Tags: objective-c, vimeo

To have an ability to upload i have to get upload ticket. But after checking it looks like invalid.
 After I create new ticket I check it and get the error 702. Please help. i've checked the parameters and they looks fine.

```
    //vimeo.videos.upload.getTicket
    NSURL *ticketRequestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://vimeo.com/api/rest/v2?format=json&method=vimeo.videos.upload.getTicket"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *ticketRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:ticketRequestURL];
    [ticketRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [auth authorizeRequest:ticketRequest];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:ticketRequest queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *ticketRequestResponse, NSData *ticketRequestData, NSError *ticketRequestError) {
        NSString *ticketRequestResponseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:ticketRequestData encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy];
        NSDictionary *d = [[parser objectWithString:ticketRequestResponseString] objectForKey:@"ticket"];
        NSString *identifier = [d objectForKey:@"id"];

        //vimeo.videos.upload.checkTicket
        NSURL *ticketCheckRequestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://vimeo.com/api/rest/v2?format=json&method=vimeo.videos.upload.checkTicket"];
        NSMutableURLRequest *ticketCheckRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:ticketCheckRequestURL];
        [ticketCheckRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [ticketCheckRequest setValue:identifier forHTTPHeaderField:@"ticket_id"];

        [auth authorizeRequest:ticketCheckRequest];
        [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:ticketCheckRequest queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *ticketRequestResponse, NSData *ticketRequestData, NSError *ticketRequestError) {
            NSString *ticketCheckRequestResponseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:ticketRequestData encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy];
            NSLog(@"%@", ticketCheckRequestResponseString);

        }];
    }];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm... Specifying ticket_id in the URL solved my problem.

```
NSURL *ticketCheckRequestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://vimeo.com/api/rest/v2?format=json&method=vimeo.videos.upload.checkTicket&ticket_id=%@", identifier]];
```

Comment: Do you have to be approved for upload first? I get a 500 error trying to create a ticket.

Comment: Have you checked your quota first?

Comment: I haven't, will that tell me if upload is enabled?

Comment: well, it will tell you whether upload is possible=)

Comment: Still fails even with upload access approved, wish they had an iOS SDK.